# spring security - identify browser/user-agent uniquely

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-security, user-agent

Is there any way to identify that two or more frequent requests are coming from exactly same browser/user-agent? I am using spring version 3.0 framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a cookie with a unique id to the browser which sent the requests.

Following requests will be sent with that cookie, and you can use its value to check if this browser made requests to your service.

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CookieValue;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    Map<String, String> agents = new HashMap<>();

    @GetMapping("/foo")
    public void foo(HttpServletResponse response, @CookieValue("agent-id") String agentId) {
        // If the cookie is not present in the browser, the value of agentId is null
        if (agentId == null) {
            String newAgentId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            agents.put(newAgentId, "request specific information");
            Cookie newAgentIdCookie = new Cookie("agent-id", newAgentId);
            response.addCookie(newAgentIdCookie);
            System.out.println("Now I know you");
        } else if (agents.containsKey(agentId)) {
            System.out.println(agents.get(agentId));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: if user request comes from two machines. those machine has same browser with same version. then?

Comment: @bytegroup, does this answer your question now?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your answer is surely helpful. But I am not supposed to use cookie.

Comment: You should add it to the question. Anyway, you should read about browser fingerprinting (for example https://pixelprivacy.com/resources/browser-fingerprinting).